# fetch the value as array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to fetch the records and display as array.`select * from album_comment where SUB_ID='$id'` displays the row as displayed in image.
   [image]

```
 $sql = "select * from album_comment where SUB_ID='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or sqlerrorhandler("(" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error(), $sql, __LINE__);
while ($comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
    $datas = json_decode($content);
 }
 echo $get_like = json_encode($content);
```

I want to fetch the value as

```
$datas=[{"name":"hello","commentuser":"desc 259 desc","id":8,"date":"2015-12-09T05:40:12.773Z","displayDate":"Wed Dec 09 2015 11:10:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)8","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0},

{"name":"hnnb","commentuser":"hjh ghj  ghj ghj","id":68,"date":"2015-12-09T06:00:44.718Z","displayDate":"Wed Dec 09 2015 11:30:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)68","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0},

{"name":"56844","commentuser":"689 498 4849 48","id":45,"date":"2015-12-09T06:03:03.178Z","displayDate":"Wed Dec 09 2015 11:33:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)45","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0},

{"name":"dcfg","commentuser":"bbnbvbvbnbb","id":60,"date":"2015-12-09T06:49:10.875Z","displayDate":"Wed Dec 09 2015 12:19:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)60","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this,

```
while ($comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
    $datas[] = json_decode($content);// capture in array
}
echo $get_like = json_encode($datas);// encode array here
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put $datas[] instead of $datas in while loop.

```
$sql = "select * from album_comment where SUB_ID='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or sqlerrorhandler("(" . mysql_errno() . ")      " . mysql_error(), $sql, __LINE__);
while ($comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
    $datas[] = json_decode($content);
}
echo $get_like = json_encode($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to save it all to the array like

```
$datas = array();
while ($comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
    $datas[] = json_decode($content);
}
echo $get_like = json_encode($datas);
```